# clearcase: find -name not allow multiple patterns?

Tags: find, clearcase, cleartool

I wanna find `*.cs` and `*.cpp` files through `cleartool find` command. But it failed.

```
cleartool find "M:\test_view\code" -name "*.cs *.cpp"  -print
```

Nothing can be found based on above even there are matched files in that folder.

How to set multiple file-name patterns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [query language](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm) offer some possibility for Compound queries (`query || query`)

But the [cleartool find](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) has none of those operators for the `-name` option.

The best you can do, following the **[cleartool wildcard syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/wildcards_ccase.htm)**, is

```
cleartool find "M:\test_view\code" -name "*.c[sp]*" -print
```

Comment: All right, the documentation **is** there, it's just well hidden. I'll try to stay away from things I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @MvanGeest: no problem ;) Your answer was well intentioned (I remember trying myself those same options with the `cleartool find` a few years ago), but that 'find' is really a different beast from the Gnu one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late but perhaps this will help someone.
One option is to wrap this is a for loop:

```
    :: namelist.txt contains a list of file types  ( *.cs, *.cpp, )

FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN (c:\bin\namelist.txt) DO ( cleartool find "M:\test_view\code" -all -type f -name %%A -print)
```

Answer (score -1):

It lookslike cleartool wraps the unix style find utility.

If that is right you might be able to use '-or'

```
$ find -type f -name '*.cs' -or '*.cpp' -print
```

Comment: seems -or does not be supported in window